# Using printf to print out the time before running a program in Crontab giving an "invalid directive" error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, printf

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 and trying to setup a crontab task.

I want the date and time to be printed to the console before the task starts all of which get's logged to a log file.

This is what I have currently.

```
{ printf "\%(\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S)T  Started Task\n"; <run task> } >> /path/to/log/file
```

When I type `printf "%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T  Started Task\n"` I get the expected output:

`2021-10-20 15:22:03  Started Task`

However, in the crontab I know you have to escape out the `"%"` with `\`. Except even after escaping out all the `%` I end up with a error :

`/bin/sh: 1: printf: %(: invalid directive`

No matter how a try and format the crontab I still end up with the same error.

If anyone know what I have done wrong please help me, thank you.

My specific cronjob is as follows:

```
0 * * * * { printf "\%(\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S)T  Updating Certs\n"; sudo certbot renew  --post-hook "systemctl reload nginx.service postfix.service dovecot.service"; } >> /home/ubuntu/logs/certbot.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron uses `sh` as shell. Your code (`printf` with feature `T`) expects `bash` (version >= 4.2). I suggest to add this in a separate line before your cronjob to force `bash` as shell.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! Had no idea it was using a different shell.

Answer (score 2):

**cron** can be surprising because its working directory is not `$HOME` and its default shell is `/bin/sh` instead of the user shell.

While writing your crontab, you have to keep in mind that:

- Using full-paths is almost mandatory.
- When grouping instructions with curly-brackets `{ }`, you must put a semi-colon at the end of the last instruction.
- With the default `/bin/sh`, `printf` can be limited to POSIX features (which means that it'll not understand the `%()T` construct).

That said, here's how you can make do of `/bin/sh` for your purpose:

```
0 * * * * { date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S  Started Task'; <command>; } >> /full/path/to/log/file
```

A completely different solution is to change your crontab's shell, like [Cyrus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69649806/3387716) is suggesting.