# Weird result with Bash's printf '%(%F %T)T'

Tags: bash, date, printf

How do you explain this? Is it a bug or did I overlook something?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

printf '%(%F %T)T\n' 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3
```

```
1970-01-01 00:00:03
1970-01-01 00:00:02
1970-01-01 00:00:01
1970-01-01 00:00:00
2023-08-16 19:31:33
2023-08-14 22:56:58
1969-12-31 23:59:57
```

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the behaviour of -1 and -2 - this should explain that: `Two special argument values may be used: -1 represents the current time, and -2 represents the time the shell was invoked. `

Comment: Btw.: Two years ago, we touched on the subject [%(datefmt)T](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69648885/3776858) without the final negative numbers. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `-1` and `-2` are defined. From `man bash`:

> `%(datefmt)T`: causes printf to output the date-time string resulting from using datefmt as a format string for strftime(3).  The corresponding  argument is an integer representing the number of seconds since the epoch.  Two special argument values may
> be used: **-1 represents the current time**, and **-2 represents the time the shell was invoked**.  If no  argument  is  specified, conversion behaves as if -1 had been given.  This is an exception to the usual printf behavior.

Comment: It's not really that only `-1` and `-2` are defined, it's that they're defined to have a specific meaning different from all other numbers in that context. So `printf '%(%F %T)T\n' 0` is defined to be the start of the epoch and `printf '%(%F %T)T\n' -3` is defined to be 3 seconds before the start of the epoch while `-1` and `-2` are defined as you explained.

Comment: @EdMorton Is that info not already in `man bash` ? `The corresponding argument is an integer representing the number of seconds since the epoch`

Comment: @Philippe yes it is, I'm just clarifying Cyrus's statement that `Only -1 and -2 are defined.` and applying what that means to the current example.